# Angular Material CDK Drop Event not fireing

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-cdk

I'm trying to use Angular material to drag drop a free node. It's not part of a list but I would like to know when the item has been dropped. I'm not sure how I can bind to this event.

I simply want to know when the node has been dropped.

here is my code so far:

```
    <svg id="svgCanvas" >

    <g *ngFor="let link of linkPaths">
        <path [attr.d]="link"></path>
    </g>

    <g *ngFor="let node of nodes" id="nodesGroup">
        <circle class="node" [attr.cx]="node.x" [attr.cy]="node.y + 45" [attr.r]="settings.nodes.radius"
            (click)="nodeClick($event)"  (dragEnd)="drop($event, node)" [attr.data-selected]="node.data.selected" cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary="#svgCanvas" ></circle>
    </g>

</svg>
```

I want the dragEnd event to fire and call my drop function in the component's code.

```
private drop(event) {
   console.log('drag end')
}
```

The click event seems to work but the drop won't fire.

I can see that Lists support the drop feature but I am not using my drag drop for a list. These are free moving nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the (cdkDragEnded) event
`(cdkDragEnded)="drop($event, node)"`.

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fk9wpa

```html
<div class="example-box" (cdkDragEnded)="drop($event)" cdkDrag>
  Contents of dragable element
</div>
```

In your case:

```html
    <g *ngFor="let node of nodes" id="nodesGroup">
        <circle class="node" [attr.cx]="node.x" [attr.cy]="node.y + 45" [attr.r]="settings.nodes.radius" (click)="nodeClick($event)" (cdkDragEnded)="drop($event, node)" [attr.data-selected]="node.data.selected" cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary="#svgCanvas" ></circle>
    </g>
```

Comment: Hi Michel Sorry but this seems to be for a list. I explicitly mentioned that I'm not using lists and your answer lacks any detail... try adding code examples etc to improve your answer.I know you're new to Stack Overflow so I'm just giving you some feedback.

Comment: Hey, your right i changed my answer. cdkDropListDropped is for list (in combination with CdkDropList). I now changed it to cdkDragEnded. That should work becouse it's not for a list but works in combination with CdkDrag. Hope it helps.

And I added a stackblitz to demonstrate trigger of drop function on dragEnd.

Comment: Ah thank you Maichel, in the end I just implemented drag and drop myself. It actually wasn't that hard but if I can reduce my code base with this it would be worth it. Thank you. I'll check it works with the rewrite and I'll set an accepted answer when I'm at a point I can test it. Thanks again.